# Видеокарта AMD и игра на LWJGL

Tags: java, разработка-игр, amd, lwjgl

Доброе время суток. Кто-нибудь знает, как драйвера видеокарт от производителя AMD определяют, является ли программа игрой? Есть java прога, написанная на LWJGL, но, само собой, сканер игр в интерфейсе AMD не находит её, только если вручную добавлять. Можно ли как-то добавив какой-то кусочек кода в прогу заставить AMD воспринимать её как игру? Или для этого нужен нативный код на С++?

Comment: А как вы узнаете что перед Вами игра? Unity,Unreal, Steam  в заголовках  файлов  содержат  исчерпывающую  информацию.

Comment: Что за заголовки файлов? Я просто только в java понимаю. Или это намёк на то, что AMD считает за игры только Steam, Unity и Unreal продукты?

Comment: Не смешите, человек который только  начинает  изучать  java не будет писать  для LWJGL на  java (там  сплошное  JNI). По теме.  У каждого типа файлов  в голове находятся магические байты, они разные,  у unity свой набор  машии и в заголовках указано, что это за  приложение. Но думаю вашем случае все проще производитель игры заявлеет о поддержке видеокарты  или  владелец  магазина (Steam , Aplpe)  указывает, что в его магазине игра.  Например  amd не определял  раньше wargaming  потомстал  определять. .  но я могу ошибаться в мире все  быстро меняется.